# how to find the value of a cond?

Tags: scheme, racket

I just started racket so excuse me if this is a dumb question. Can someone tell me what exactly I am doing wrong? I am trying to find the value of:

```
(cond
  [(<= (string-length s) 5) 10]
  [(string=? s “hello”) 50]
  [(string=? (substring s 1 4) “ell”) 25]
  [else 130])
```

when when s is (i) `"hello"` and s is (ii) `"hellos"` .

I did one similar with numbers where all I had to do was define it with a number and had no problems. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

edit-

like for this one. Where they ask for the value of n when its 150000.
    I simply define n as 150000I get "mb" as the value.

```
;;(define n 15000)

(cond
  [(<= n 1000) (number->string n)]
  [(<= n 5000) 
(string->symbol 
(string-append "num" (number->string n)))]
  [else (substring 
(string-append "number" (number->string n)) 2 4)])
```

i am trying to do the ame with the above. if this makes any sense.

Comment: Have you looked at the following yet?  http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3acond%29

Comment: Why do you believe it's wrong? what's the expected output for each case?

Comment: i edited to see if it makes any more sense.

Comment: @KevinR. you didn't answer my question. What's the expected result for  "hello"? and for "hellos"?

Comment: thats what iam trying to find out myself by plugging in "hello" into s like I did for the 2nd problem (where I plugged in 15000 in n) in which I got "mb" as an output.

Comment: @KevinR. Take a look at my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that strings must be surrounded by `""` to work, in your code you're using a similar but not-quite-right kind of double quotes. Try this instead:

```
(define s "hello")

(cond
  [(<= (string-length s) 5) 10]
  [(string=? s "hello") 50]
  [(string=? (substring s 1 4) "ell") 25]
  [else 130])
```

Besides that, the code has no errors per-se, but it's possible that the result obtained is not the one you expected because of the *order* in which the different conditions appear in the `cond`, try switching some, reorganizing them, etc.

Bear in mind that the conditions are evaluated from top-to-bottom and the first condition that is true will be executed. For example, if the input is `"hello"`, `(<= (string-length s) 5)` gets evaluated and executed before `(string=? s "hello")`, because the first condition is true, and the second condition is never reached and therefore never executed.

Comment: @KevinR. If this solved the problem, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark to its left

Comment: ahhhh. Of course I only I would miss something so small. Thanks!